# How can I draw a bezier curve polyline on a bing map wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps, bezier

Bing maps library for wpf seems not to include any helper to draw a bezier curve. 
It has MapPolyLine which can be used to draw straight lines between n points.
Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps does not support curved geometries directly, so instead can approximate the shape of a curved line by creating a polyline containing several small segments.

Hope this article will help
https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/geodesics-on-bing-maps-v7/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using geodesic, if you don't care about being spatially accurate you can take your coordinates, convert them to pixel coordinates at zoom level 19 using the code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Then pass the pixel coordinates through a standard Bezier curve algorithm. Take the resulting values and convert them back to locations.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck using WPF and VS Basic and no available Google API or Microsoft Maps API to allow me to draw a geodesic curve representing a flight from A to B.
Found reference [1] which provided the maths for the answer.

```
    Public Function GetGeodesicPath(startLocation As Location, endLocation As Location, segments As Integer) As LocationCollection
    Dim lc As New LocationCollection
    lc.Add(startLocation)

    ' Convert coordinates from degrees to Radians
    Dim lat1 = startLocation.Latitude * Math.PI / 180
    Dim lon1 = startLocation.Longitude * Math.PI / 180
    Dim lat2 = endLocation.Latitude * Math.PI / 180
    Dim lon2 = endLocation.Longitude * Math.PI / 180

    ' Calculate the length of the route
    Dim length = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((Math.Sin((lat1 - lat2) / 2)), 2) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Pow((Math.Sin((lon1 - lon2) / 2)), 2)))

    ' Calculate positions at fixed intervals along the route - 32 segments to provide a smooth curve

    For counter = 1 To segments

        Dim segmentlength = (counter / segments)
        Dim A = Math.Sin((1 - segmentlength) * length) / Math.Sin(length)
        Dim B = Math.Sin(segmentlength * length) / Math.Sin(length)

        ' Obtain 3D cartesian co-ordinates of each point

        Dim x = A * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lon1) + B * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Cos(lon2)
        Dim y = A * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Sin(lon1) + B * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Sin(lon2)
        Dim z = A * Math.Sin(lat1) + B * Math.Sin(lat2)

        Dim segmentLat = Math.Atan2(z, Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)))
        Dim segmentLon = Math.Atan2(y, x)

        ' Create a Location by converting lat lon to degrees
        Dim location As New Location
        location.Latitude = segmentLat / (Math.PI / 180)
        location.Longitude = segmentLon / (Math.PI / 180)

        ' Add location to Location Collection
        lc.Add(location)

    Next

    Return lc

End Function
```

This returns a locationCollection which can be added to your mapPolyline